# Custom Mesh Analysis overlay via Python add-on

Tags: python, add-on

I've been experimenting with using Blender for civil engineering where grades/slopes are an important factor of design. In the screenshot below you can see face grade visualized on the face itself via a blender add-on I wrote, with the controls stuck into the bottom of the panel seen on the right.

Is it possible to add a custom `Mesh Analysis` that would be driven by the same logic? I have a look at the [MeshStatVis documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshStatVis.html#bpy.types.MeshStatVis.type) and it seems like type is limited to predefined properties: `enum in [‘OVERHANG’, ‘THICKNESS’, ‘INTERSECT’, ‘DISTORT’, ‘SHARP’], default ‘OVERHANG’`. How can one go about implementing custom type and logic in here?

[image]